# Fix $a > 0$ and let $x_1 > \sqrt a$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

[image]

My current thought is to take $x_{n+1}-x_n$ and to prove the difference is smaller than $\sqrt a$. But it won't help me to prove $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt a$.

Comment: Well, the question starts by asking you to show that the sequence is decreasing; so $x_{n + 1} - x_n < \sqrt{a}$ is useless, because you actually need to show that $x_{n + 1} - x_n \le 0$. Then you'll probably invoke a theorem about monotone convergence.

Comment: I [answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040674/approximating-sqrt2-in-rational-numbers/2108063#2108063) to this question sometimes ago, in a different context (it was required that the approximating succession $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ was made of only rational numbers, but the method of proof is basically the same).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x_1>\sqrt\alpha$, show that $x_{n+1}>\sqrt\alpha$. Then use that to show $x_{n+1}-x_n<0$, which proves the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

Therefore (it is monotonically decreasing and bounded below) the sequence has a limit $L$. The limit must satisfy:
$$
L=\frac12\left(L+\frac\alpha L\right)
$$
which means you can figure out exactly what it is.